# ASP.net page not loading CSS with error Failed to Load Resource

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, iis

I have asp.net application which I am running on local host. When I browse page loads but its not able to pick any css  and js and I get error as

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(see screenshot)** .

Any pointer as to what could be wrong here? 
[image]

On a different server, same page loads fine with all images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your paths -- you may need to use a relative path instead of an absolute.  Also, confirm that you can navigate to the css and js files from your browser using the path that you see in the console (you probably will not).  Finally, check your IIS settings and make sure you can server Static files.

Comment: thanks for your response Kevin. I can see css and jss file from browser. Where in IIS settings can I check for Statis Files?

Comment: Your mileage may vary, depending on your OS, but this usually works:

https://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/don-t-forget-to-check-quot-static-content-service-quot-in-iis7-installation

Comment: Kevin, enabling static files helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Include all your `files` or css and any from `Project PC` to `Deployment` server

Comment: Make sure you had a right permission access to your project folder in server.

Comment: thanks . Kevin suggestion helped me solved my issue. I had to turn on Static file settings. This was a fresh build machine and was missing it.